# Directory issue: Module not Found

Tags: python, pytorch, directory, operating-system, sys

I'm trying to import two modules in a main.py file. The file structure is like this

```
|Common-Folder
|
|
|__Folder
|  |___main.py
|
|
|__Tools(folder)
| |___models
| |___maze
```

inside main, I do

```
import sys import os

module_dir = os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/.../Common-folder/Tools')

if module_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_dir)

import models import maze
```

This still results in ModuleNotFound Error, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/.../main.py", line 64, in <module>
    import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Comment: The posted file structure has `Common-Folder`, but your code has `Common-folder`.  Capital `F` instead of lowercase `f`.

Comment: Thank you. Might be a bit unrelated, but what does
path.join do? does it change the module search path and will it become fixed at the directory after I run path.join?

Comment: The purpose of `os.path.join()` is to join together two or more partial directory path strings into a single directory path string.  For example calling `os.path.join('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` would produce `'a/b/c/d'`.  But it looks like you're calling it with only one directory path anyway, which is useless.  If this is your real code, you don't need to use it at all.

Comment: One of the main benefits of using `os.path.join()` is that it automatically puts the correct directory separator character in between the folder names, i.e. it uses a forward slash for unix and a backslash for windows.

Comment: Another benefit is that it knows that if any of the paths are absolute (start with a slash), it can throw away all the preceding paths.  i.e. `os.path.join('/a', 'b', '/c')` will return just `'/c'`.